# C - Matrix, random numbers

Tags: c, random, matrix, row

I wrote a code to print 5x6 matrix of numbers, but i'm trying to figure out how can I make numbers within matrix random (if possible, within interval). How similar is it to getting random numbers in rows?

```
int row[50]
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(i=0;i<50;i++){
  row[i]=rand()%31+10;
  printf("%d ", row[i]);
 }
```

I used this code earlier today for 50 random numbers within 10-40 interval.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two `for` loops:

```
int array[5][6];
srand(time(NULL));
int x, y;
for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < 6; y++) 
        array[x][y] = rand() % 31 + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jh314's answer, here's a handy function to get a random number in an interval.

```
int random_int(int min, int max) {
    return min + rand() % (max - min + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you're looking for all unique numbers in matrix :

```
int used[30];
int count=0;

int check_used(int x)
{
int i;
for(i =0; i<count;i++)
    if(used[i] == x)
     return 1;

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int r,i,j;
    int mat[5][6];

    srand (time(NULL));

    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        while(1)
        {
            r=rand()  % 31 + 10;
            if(!check_used(r))
            { mat[i][j]  = used[count++] =r;
              break;
            }
        }     
    return 0;
}
```